# Is reverse indexing broken?

Tags: python-3.x, string, indexing

What is happening here? It won't pick up the exclamation mark in reverse indexing without a kludge.

```
h = str("Hello, World!")
print(len(h))
print(h[-13:-1]) #What happened to the !
print(h[-13:-1]+h[-1])
print(len(h[-13:-1]+h[-1]))​
```

Output: 13  "Hello, World"  "Hello, World!"  13

Comment: It is not broken. Python slices are closed to the left and open to the right, i.e. `13:-1` includes `13` and excludes `-1`. If you want "from "-13 til the end", simply use `h[-13:]`

Comment: The first index is inclusive, the second index is exclusive. If you want the rest of the string, just do: `h[-13:]`.

Comment: [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Comment: Thank you. RafaelC got it first and correctly, but there is no upvote button for his reply. This board is still a mystery to me. One time I hit the down arrows to move down the page. Some people got upset. Anyway, thanks for your help people. Hope I don't get kicked for saying thank you incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Slice indexing is inclusive in front, and exclusive in back. For example,

```
h = "Hello, World!"
print(h[3:6])
# 'lo,'
```

includes indices `3`, `4`, and `5`, but *not* `6`.

When you do `[13:-1]`, you're grabbing everything from index `13` to index `-1`, but not index `-1` itself. To get "everything after 13", you can just leave the second field in the slice blank:

```
print(h[8:])
# 'orld!'
```

You can do the same to get "every character before index `8`":

```
print(h[:8])
# 'Hello, W'
```

and leaving both fields blank actually just produces a copy of the thing you're trying to slice:

```
print(h[:])
# 'Hello, World!'
```